# Oracle 12c not sufficient privileges on trigger creation

Tags: database, oracle, privileges

I want to execute code on user `IDK`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_trig
  AFTER UPDATE OF status ON TAB1
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.status = 'ZAK')
CALL log_sal(1, 5, 8);
```

I have following grants:

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO IDK;
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO IDK;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO IDK;
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO IDK;
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO IDK;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO IDK;
GRANT SELECT ON TAB1 TO IDK;
```

What grants i need more?
I won't get update/delete/insert on `TAB1`.
I am getting `error:` `not sufficient privileges`.

I created procedure from user `IDK`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_sal (
  emp_id NUMBER,
  old_sal NUMBER,
  new_sal NUMBER
)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'CaseWatch.logSal(int, float, float)';
```

Comment: Does this use have the privileges to call `log_sal`?

Comment: @Mureinik `log_sal` is procedure created by me. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: By the same user that owns the table?

Comment: @Mureinik `procedure` created by user - `IDK`. But `IDK` does not own table `TAB1`. He can make select on it via `grant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comments the TAB1 table created by different User, so the table is in a different schema, this is the main key. 
When you want to grant privileges to create a trigger on a table in different schema then you need to use:

> `GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO IDK;`

`CREATE TRIGGER` => in fact giving permission to create a database trigger in the grantee's schema, in your case if TAB1 created by IDK then this privilege is enough.

Regarding the `CREATE ANY TRIGGER` here you can find some more interesting info:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm
2. [Grant create any trigger vs grant create trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256959/grant-create-any-trigger-vs-grant-create-trigger)